# How to reference XML data that isn't bound to a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, data-binding, asp.net-2.0

C# newbie asking, so if the question is stupid or the answer is really obvious, it's probably because I don't fully understand how `XmlDataSource` works.

Given the following XML file "super-simple-xml.xml" (formatted to save some space),

```
<items>
    <item> <one id="ms">Microsoft</one>  <two>MSFT</two> </item>
    <item> <one id="in">Intel</one>      <two>INTC</two> </item>
    <item> <one id="de">Dell</one>       <two>DELL</two> </item>
</items>
```

a repeater that looks something like this,

```
<asp:Repeater id="SuperSimple" runat="server" OnItemCommand="SuperSimple_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1"><tr><th>Company</th><th>Symbol</th><th>Wrong</th></tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label Text=<%#XPath("one") %> runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:CheckBox Text=<%#XPath("two") %> runat="server" id="symbol" /></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>  
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
        <asp:Button id="buttonOne" Text="Submit!" runat="server" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and the following to bind the XML:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    XmlDataSource xmlSource = new XmlDataSource();
    xmlSource.DataFile = "super-simple-xml.xml";
    xmlSource.XPath = "items/item";

    if (!IsPostBack) // Did this to prevent an error
    {
        SuperSimple.DataSource = xmlSource;
        SuperSimple.DataBind();
    }
}
```

How would I go about pulling the `id` from each XML entry into a class or variable?

The idea here is that I am displaying the items in a Repeater. I added checkboxes, so I can check any of the `<two>` entries, and then press Submit. When it posts back, I want to store the checked entry in a class I've made. Getting `<one>` and `<two>` in are easy enough because they have IDs in the Repeater that I can reference. But the `id` attribute in the XML is never called, so I don't know how to get to it. I want to have the `id` in the class to reference as I pass the data along. Is this possible, and how do I do it?

Comment: To clarify your question, are you trying to get out the values of the id attribute within your 'Page_Load' C# method or are you trying to pull out the id value within the mark up, eg just like you are with 'one' and 'two'?

Comment: But, ultimately whatever works. @Sean addressed the latter situation and it seems workable. I was just under the assumption that if the XML file was being accessed by the page, I could get to it without having to bind it to something.

Answer (score 1):

Use the XPath @ syntax for getting an attribute:

```
<%# XPath("one/@id") %>
```

You can bind this expression to a HiddenField and access that in the postback:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidID" Value='<%# XPath("one/@id") %>' />
```

Add a command button to the `<ItemTemplate>`:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnGetID" Text="Get ID" CommandName="GetID" />
```

In the OnItemCommand event:

```
protected void SuperSimple_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //check the item type, headers won't contain the control
    if (e.CommandName == "GetID")
    {
        //find the control and put it's value into a variable
        HiddenField hidID = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hidID");
        string strID = hidID.Value;
    }
}
```

This is an alternative (I originally posted because I was confused by the name of your OnItemCommand event and thought you wanted the values at DataBinding time):

In your `<ItemTemplate>`:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnGetID" OnClick="btnGetID_Click" Text="Get ID" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void btnGetID_Click(object sender, e as EventArgs)
{
    //sender is the button
    Button btnGetID = (Button)sender;
    //the button's parent control is the RepeaterItem
    RepeaterItem theItem = (RepeaterItem)sender.Parent;
    //find the hidden field in the RepeaterItem
    HiddenField hidID = (HiddenField)theItem.FindControl("hidID");
    //assign to variable
    string strID = hidID.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps, problem could be in wrong xml structure.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1813664.aspx/1?getting+xml+node+id+number